# Android to node.js communication

Tags: java, android, node.js, websocket

I saw there are a couple of similar threads but i could not find my answer.

I'm making and android app, an i want to use node as server for real time communication.

I really cannot get this to work.

Probably I'm making many many things wrong but i like to try to understand.

My server is as simple as

```js
var http = require('http'),  
io = require('socket.io'),
server = http.createServer(function(req, res){ 
     res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); 
     res.end(':)'); 
});
server.listen(8080);
var socket = io.listen(server); 
socket.on('connection', function(client){
    client.send("hello");
    console.log("connected!");
});
```

and this works... I tried this with a web app and I can connect.

But I can't with java..

I tried [kryonet](http://code.google.com/p/kryonet/) but I get an exception like "connected but timeout on registration"

I tried [weberknecht](http://code.google.com/p/weberknecht/) I get a "error while creating socket to ws://184.xxxxxx:8080"

I tried [TooTallNate](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket), no luck, it just call onClose method.

I tried [jWebSocket](http://jwebsocket.org/) but I couldn't get it to work...

So I'm here, asking for help, does anyone knows how to get this done? any suggestion?

P.S.
for TooTallNate I'm using something like this:

```js
Net net = new Net(new URI("ws://184.xxxxxx:8080"),WebSocketDraft.DRAFT76);
```

might the problem be here?

UPDATE:
I handled this! after a good sleep I had the idea, I was using socket.io, bad idea... now I use [Node Websocket Server](http://static.brandedcode.com/nws-docs/) with  [weberknecht](http://code.google.com/p/weberknecht/). The server looks like this:

```js
var ws = require("websocket-server");

var server = ws.createServer();

server.addListener("connection", function(client){
    console.log("new connection");
    client.send("aaaaaa");
    client.addListener("message", function(msg){
    });
});

server.listen(8080);
```

and the client:

```java
try {
    URI url = new URI("ws://184.106.69.64:8080/");
    WebSocket websocket = new WebSocketConnection(url);
    websocket.setEventHandler(new WebSocketEventHandler() {
        public void onOpen(){
            System.out.println("--open");
        }    
        public void onMessage(WebSocketMessage message){
            System.out.println("--received message: " + message.getText());
        }   
        public void onClose(){
            System.out.println("--close");
        }
    });

    websocket.connect();
    websocket.send("hello world");
}
catch (WebSocketException wse) {
    wse.printStackTrace();
}
catch (URISyntaxException use) {
    use.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I believe the problem is the websocketdraft. There are 3 drafts lying around, 76, 00 and 06. Socket.io is pretty bleeding edge with keeping up with the new drafts but I doubt your Java libraries are.

Comment: if you're using an android app as a client instead of a browser there's no point in using websockets. websockets are made for server/browser setups.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm the author of node-websocket-server (nws), and I'm pretty sure the reason for node-websocket-server working and socket.io not, is due to the implementation of each. NWS will auto negotiate the right draft to use, and it also has a hopefully 90-100% compliance with the drafts of 76 and 75.

As for socket.io, I can't comment too much, but the last I looked, it's websocket implementation was rather poorly implemented.

I'm currently working on a project at the moment called node-websocket-protocol, which will be able to be used by socket.io, faye, etc as to provide them with a really reliable and compliant websocket implementation. This will also replace the current implementation in node-websocket-server in version 2.0.0.

As a side note, if you'd rather not host your own websocket server, you could look at using Pusher.com, who're actually my employers.

[Update] As for whether websockets are the most appropriate technology choice for your application, is a matter of what type of data and interaction your application needs. On a mobile device, it may be best to use something like urbanairship or notifio if you're just sending push notifications.

Regards,
Micheil Smith

Comment: Many thanks for your opinion, know i have a better view of the situation, anyway my app is a game and need a bit more than just notifications, thanks for suggestion anyway!

Comment: I would suggest the Android C2DM library and the iPhone Notification system, personally. Reinventing the wheel is often a headache.

Comment: @Micheil Smith: What is Pusher actually providing if you can set up node.js server and communicate with it from Java with just a few lines (as seen above in the question)?

Answer (score 2):

Like Raynos said the websocket spec is still a draft(changes). Maybe you could ask Guillermo Rauch(Author socket.io) which draft he is using and find the proper Websocket library. At [his github page](https://github.com/guille) you can find his email address and try to send him an email(short).

You could also try to use another transport(long-polling) and implement the [spec](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-spec) yourself I guess.

But in my opinion you should be using Google's [c2dm](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html)(Big players are already using this and will be very gently to your phone's battery) instead to push updates to phone in realtime. I already have a lot of applications installed that are using c2dm like for example [whatsapp](http://www.whatsapp.com/)(awesome). You could be using [notifo's api](https://api.notifo.com/) to simplify your work. Then simply install [there android program](http://notifo.com/mobile_apps/android) to receive the desired notifications. There is also a [node module(npm)](https://github.com/mape/node-notifo) available for you to use (easy :))

Comment: I would recommend pinging him in #socket.io on freenode rather then email.

Comment: @Raynos that might even be better(more realtime). Those people from learnboost rock :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend

- Android:
  https://github.com/stellaeof/java-websocket-client
- Node Websockets:http://static.brandedcode.com/nws-docs/