# android socket connection, inputStream freezing on readline with socket.io or node websocket server

Tags: android, sockets, websocket, inputstream

im using [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) and [weberknecht](http://code.google.com/p/weberknecht/) to convert an inputStream to a string and connect to a websocket [see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499543/android-to-node-js-communication) post]. Weberknecht threw me out, so im trying a very simple Socket-Connection to get any answer from the server. The Problem is, i can't read the inputStream. I don't know why.

NOTE:
On Iphone the Websocket-Server works. [i know "websocket /= socket" ... im just trying everything here to get ANY answer from the server]

My code:

```
        try {
            Socket sock = new Socket("62.212.88.234", 15000);
            OutputStream out = sock.getOutputStream();
            InputStream in = sock.getInputStream();

            Log.e("SKT", "Reading input [! PROBLEM HERE !]");
            String string = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(in,
                    "UTF-8"));

            Log.e("SKT", "Answer [! NEVER REACHED !]:" + string);
            sock.close();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.e("SKT", "UnknownHostException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("SKT", "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

Thanks for the Help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/io/CharStreams.html) for `CharStreams.toString` says:

> Reads all characters from a Readable object into a String.

My guess is that the remote end does not close the socket, so there's no end-of-stream to consume, thus the freeze.

Comment: have thought the same. But how it be closed? Iphones can cannot to the same socket without problems. Only android can't. I thought its a portproblem maybe.

Comment: I think you are missing what I'm saying. Try the simplest socket example - just reading from the input stream - you'll see the data.

Comment: how do i read it on the fly before it's closed? BufferedReader expects line-ends. You mean byte-by-byte?

Comment: Try using `InputStream.read(byte[] b)` to read into byte array, not byte-by-byte, more like block-by-block.

Comment: okay thank you. Tried the phonegap websocket approach and saw in the code that they are reading block by block too. It works now. Thank you.