# Android phone to Chrome communication and Google OAUTH

Tags: android, google-chrome, oauth, google-chrome-extension, websocket

Alright I have two questions which are interrelated.

1. Using Google OAUTH can I send communications between an android phone and a chrome browser extension? I was thinking that I could write some info somewhere and it would be stored in the account info or something? This was just a theory (not really supported by any info I have read)
2. If that doesn't work I was going to use [Android to node.js communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499543/android-to-node-js-communication) idea using http://static.brandedcode.com/nws-docs/ documentation for an android to websocket server communication then a chrome extension to the websocket server. I was then going to use the gmail from each device to verify they belong to each other and pass the message that way.

Does anyone have any knowledge about how feasible this is/how challenging it is? I also need to know how secure the communication is if I only rely on a gmail account. Is there any information done by using OAUTH or another method that I could use to secure it more?

Finally is there a method to turn a chrome extension into a websocket server? That way I could just bypass the need for an external server and any sort of verification method.

I'm willing to do some work and/or research if necessary so list anything you think I should look into and any ideas you might have. I'm thinking of having a nice coding weekend so I will be playing around with this A LOT!

I appreciate any help that anyone can give.

Comment: eric - did you find an answer to your question?